# Entropy at zero kelvin for pure atom crystal

Tags: physical-chemistry, entropy

The third law of thermodynamics describes that the entropy of pure ideal crystaline substance is zero.

Now we know that in practice this could be wrong for water (for example) because of its different crystalization states with nearly the same energy.
(Book: Atkins, Physical Chemistry 4th, German Translation, page 99)

But: Is the entropy always zero at zero kelvin for ideal crystalised and pure elements? Because there shouldn't be a difference in position of atoms.

Comment: + Maybe someone can give the literature notice to the answer, cause I couldn't find any.

Comment: Are you referring to different phases of ice?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice#Phases?

Comment: I'm refering the an atkins text parts (physical chemistry book), which describes that water can have different crystalization states cause of different bond length configuration at zero kelvin. And therefore an entropy greater than zero.

Comment: Could you please add that to the question too? Would clarify things a bit...

Comment: For a perfect sample of  crystalline Argon, for example,  one would expect entropy to be zero at zero, but not for CO where the orientation can be CO-CO-CO or CO-OC-CO etc so the experimental entropy is not zero for easily explained reasons. Water will be even more complicated.

Comment: That is what I thought of, but just don't know. :-) Do you have a literature source for this statement? Althought it seem to be right!

Comment: If you want to have it "entropy-free", you need isotopically pure crystals. Although the difference is hard to find, chemically. The size of the crystal could still be regarded as entropic, at least if you have more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to underline some perceived inherent difference between water and elemental compounds. There is none. A crystal of water ice, so to put it, is as crystalline as any other crystal.

There are quite a few crystals (indeed, certain elemental compounds are among them) that exhibit some kind of disorder; as you lower the temperature, their molecules (or atoms, or ions) freeze in somewhat different positions having nearly the same energy, so if you extrapolate to zero, you'll see that they retain some significant entropy even then. This has nothing to do with the Third law. These crystals are **not ideal** by a wide margin, and they are not going to become more ideal anytime soon, especially if you keep them near the absolute zero.

On a side note, the words "*practice*" and "*at 0 K*" do not sit well together, but that's another story.

Comment: So for a conclusion: Ideal crystal always has an entropy of zero at zero kelvin. Cause when they do not have a value of zero, these crystals are far away from being ideal.

But what about pure element crystals now?

Comment: You are still relying on a distinction which is simply not there. Pure element crystals are no different from any other crystals.